# What should my /etc/network/interfaces look like

Tags: networking, server, dns, iptables, firewall

I’ve relatively new to Ubuntu/Linux and have been mainly following online guides to achieve what i would like.

I think however, i have currently messed up my /etc/network/interfaces

When I restart my machine, i have to enter " sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT && sudo iptables -F INPUT && sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT && sudo iptables -F OUTPUT", This line was used after i installed NordVPN and the line was given to me by one of their agents to get the machine working with NordVPN.

I have since uninstalled NordVPN but still have to enter that comment if i restart my machine if i want to SSH into the machine.

I also have Plex running on the machine, which is showing error "Error issuing curl_easy_perform(handle): 6" which i believe is DNS related.

```
Jun 26, 2020 19:12:26.350 [0x7f5b70cab700] Warning — JobManager: Could not find job for handle 8077
Jun 26, 2020 19:12:30.429 [0x7f5b70cab700] Warning — JobManager: Could not find job for handle 1423
Jun 26, 2020 19:12:32.759 [0x7f5b70cab700] Warning — JobManager: Could not find job for handle 13783
Jun 26, 2020 19:12:32.760 [0x7f5ac17fa700] Warning — SLOW QUERY: It took 67910.000000 ms to retrieve 96 items.
Jun 26, 2020 19:12:43.911 [0x7f5b60ff9700] Warning — Held transaction for too long (../Library/MetadataItem.cpp:6629): 0.300000 seconds
Jun 26, 2020 19:13:40.326 [0x7f5ae1ffb700] Warning — HTTP error requesting PUT https://plex.tv/devices/e39856839c0b4d803a9fe1b78319fc5e360d8c29?Connection[][uri]=http://192.168.1.161:32400&Connection[][uri]=http://[fdcf:70eb:f18f:1:410:7c62:9f65:d2fb]:32400&Connection[][uri]=http://[fdcf:70eb:f18f:1:88ed:487b:1d59:e5eb]:32400&httpsEnabled=1&httpsRequired=0&dnsRebindingProtection=1&natLoopbackSupported=0&X-Plex-Token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (6, Couldn't resolve host name) (Could not resolve host: plex.tv)
Jun 26, 2020 19:13:40.326 [0x7f5ae1ffb700] Warning — MyPlex: Updating device connections failed, retrying in 40 seconds.
Jun 26, 2020 19:15:00.438 [0x7f5ac3fff700] Warning — HTTP error requesting PUT https://plex.tv/devices/e39856839c0b4d803a9fe1b78319fc5e360d8c29?Connection[][uri]=http://192.168.1.161:32400&Connection[][uri]=http://[fdcf:70eb:f18f:1:410:7c62:9f65:d2fb]:32400&Connection[][uri]=http://[fdcf:70eb:f18f:1:88ed:487b:1d59:e5eb]:32400&httpsEnabled=1&httpsRequired=0&dnsRebindingProtection=1&natLoopbackSupported=0&X-Plex-Token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (6, Couldn't resolve host name) (Could not resolve host: plex.tv)
Jun 26, 2020 19:15:00.438 [0x7f5ac3fff700] Warning — MyPlex: Updating device connections failed, retrying in 80 seconds.
```

to complicate matters, I have two Docker containers relating to DNS;

[lancache](https://lancache.net/)
[pihole](https://hub.docker.com/r/pihole/pihole/)

My motherboard also has 2 (technically 3, but the third is IPMI and seem unaffected by any of this) network ports (192.168.1.160 & 161)

I’m confused and at a loss as to solve my problem, if I disable any of the Dockers, I still have the same problems, any help would be appreciated.

Ideally I would like my router (192.168.1.1) to point to the Lancahe (192.168.1.160), which will cache any steam etc games for future local downloading, which will point to Piehole (192.168.1.161) to stop advertising DNS queries.

*Pihole has 30+ whitelisted domains linked to plex

*I have also installed a 10gbe card for a P2P link but have disabled this as it complicates things even more, and I’d like to get this working without it for now.*

ifconfig:

```
r-0f8d4ecbc972: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        ether 02:42:30:7e:3f:05  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-9b6281dee795: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:19ff:fe48:7d59  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:19:48:7d:59  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24341  bytes 7558978 (7.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62413  bytes 10645146 (10.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-9f05bb2df28a: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.28.255.255
        ether 02:42:31:ef:d2:01  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-c5da9849f46b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:9d:ea:c4:7d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-cbb429b4b9c0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:32ff:fea7:c8a9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:32:a7:c8:a9  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32842  bytes 4098603 (4.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60814  bytes 7956217 (7.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:32ff:fea7:a13f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:32:a7:a1:3f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8259314  bytes 958663330 (958.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 26148527  bytes 43332912835 (43.3 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp129s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:02:c9:51:35:de  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1797  bytes 299315 (299.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 546  bytes 58344 (58.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp2s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.160  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fdcf:70eb:f18f:1:d166:5254:c194:e381  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::939e:8124:c941:e95d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdcf:70eb:f18f:1:eeb0:87c2:1239:7aae  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:25:90:e4:96:50  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 31205807  bytes 44447143840 (44.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8628414  bytes 942953776 (942.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdfc20000-dfc3ffff

enp2s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.161  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fdcf:70eb:f18f:1:88ed:487b:1d59:e5eb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::3f41:4183:478e:ff28  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdcf:70eb:f18f:1:d408:d0c7:296a:e055  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 00:25:90:e4:96:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 200136  bytes 43803097 (43.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18892  bytes 2550230 (2.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xdfc00000-dfc1ffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1213770  bytes 976632859 (976.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1213770  bytes 976632859 (976.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth0f47f34: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::a8b6:94ff:feb8:577a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::a8b6:94ff:feb8:577a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether aa:b6:94:b8:57:7a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 69339  bytes 14837909 (14.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 73286  bytes 34119189 (34.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth117d7eb: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9c6e:26ff:fee5:cc79  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 9e:6e:26:e5:cc:79  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 940  bytes 978212 (978.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11787  bytes 2659059 (2.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth3911bac: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::74e7:5eff:fe6b:d24b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 76:e7:5e:6b:d2:4b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 159  bytes 316137 (316.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29867  bytes 3080261 (3.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth50f68a5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::8c70:1ff:fed4:ce0d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8e:70:01:d4:ce:0d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8044683  bytes 827768087 (827.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25918234  bytes 43244823479 (43.2 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth59f3cdd: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::94ac:33ff:fe55:6214  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 96:ac:33:55:62:14  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13  bytes 834 (834.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10912  bytes 1735925 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth7a4f2da: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::d4bd:15ff:fe28:66b4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d6:bd:15:28:66:b4  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24341  bytes 7899752 (7.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 62535  bytes 10661094 (10.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth9914bfe: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::141d:dcff:fee3:177a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 16:1d:dc:e3:17:7a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 144339  bytes 230708684 (230.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 178020  bytes 56528805 (56.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethc5801d2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::902e:e8ff:fe98:9c90  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 92:2e:e8:98:9c:90  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 112  bytes 7541 (7.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29792  bytes 3065124 (3.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethf491d08: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::707b:78ff:feb7:ed71  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 72:7b:78:b7:ed:71  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32571  bytes 4234713 (4.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60629  bytes 7933964 (7.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of /etc/iptables/rules.v4 (if it exists)?